# MySql Query takes forever

Tags: mysql

hi I am doing A query to get some product info, but there is something strange going on, the first query returns resultset fast (.1272s) but the second (note that I just added 1 column) takes forever to complete (28-35s), anyone know what is happening?

### query 1

```
SELECT
p.partnumberp,
p.model,
p.descriptionsmall,
p.brandname,
sum(remainderint) stockint
from
inventario_dbo.inventoryindetails ind
left join purchaseorders.product p on (p.partnumberp = ind.partnumberp)
left join inventario_dbo.inventoryin ins on (ins.inventoryinid= ind.inventoryinid)
group by partnumberp, projectid
```

### query 2

```
SELECT
p.partnumberp,
p.model,
p.descriptionsmall,
p.brandname,
p.descriptiondetail,
sum(remainderint) stockint
from
inventario_dbo.inventoryindetails inda
left join purchaseorders.product p on (p.partnumberp = inda.partnumberp)
left join inventario_dbo.inventoryin ins on (ins.inventoryinid= inda.inventoryinid)
group by partnumberp, projectid
```

Comment: Post the output of EXPLAIN on your queries.

Comment: They look identical aside from the table alias for `inventario_dbo.inventoryindetails` - is that correct?

Comment: What is the definition of the column purchaseorder.product.descriptiondetail?

Comment: what type of field is p.descriptiondetail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is descriptiondetail a really large column?  Sounds like it could be a lot of text compared to the other fields based on its name, so maybe it just takes a lot more time to read from disk, but if you could post the schema detail for the purchaseorders.product table or maybe the average length of that column that would help.

Otherswise I would try running the query a few times and see you consistently get the same time results.  Could just be load on the database server the time you got the slower result.

Comment: it was indeed a large column (varchar(10,000)) cut it down to 1000 since no description is or wil be more than 1000 chars

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't group by some columns and then select other columns unless you use aggregate functions. Only p.partnumberp and sum(remainderint) make sense here. You're doing a huge join and select and then the results for most rows just end up getting discarded.

You can make the query much faster by doing an inner select first and then joining that to the remaining tables to get your final result for the last few columns.

The inner select should look something like this:

```
select p.partnumberp, projectid, sum(remainderint) stockint
    from inventario_dbo.inventoryindetails ind
    left join purchaseorders.product p on (p.partnumberp = ind.partnumberp)
    left join inventario_dbo.inventoryin ins on (ins.inventoryinid = ind.inventoryinid)
    group by partnumberp, projectid
```

After the join:

```
select T1.partnumberp, T1.projectid, p2.model, p2.descriptionsmall, p2.brandname, T1.stockint
from
    (select p.partnumberp, projectid, sum(remainderint) stockint
        from inventario_dbo.inventoryindetails ind
        left join purchaseorders.product p on (p.partnumberp = ind.partnumberp)
        left join inventario_dbo.inventoryin ins on (ins.inventoryinid = ind.inventoryinid)
        group by partnumberp, projectid) T1
    left join purchaseorders.product p2 on (p2.partnumberp = T1.partnumberp)
```

Comment: right. make this a sub-query and join back to purchaseorders.product to get the rest of the fields

Comment: p.model, p.descriptionsmall, p.brandname cause a much larger chunk of data to group ( write out to disk & sort ), and the behavior is not defined - you get a random value back

Comment: Even though the result is typically undefined, in this case it will always be correct because it chooses the description as one of the millions (for example) of identical descriptions from the join. However even though the SQL gives the correct result, it is invalid SQL. MySQL is lenient - most other DB providers would reject this SQL entirely as invalid.